# How do I broadcast from the http interceptor?

Tags: angularjs, q

Using AngularJS 1.2

My interceptor looks like this:

```
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$log', '$rootScope', function ($q, $log, $rootScope) {
            return {
                'request': function(config) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('spin');
                    console.info('request!');
                    return config || $q.when(config);
                },
...
```

In my nav controller (which handles and binds the loader/spinner to the view):

```
$rootScope.$watch('spin', function(event) {
    console.info('spin');
    $scope.spinner++;
});
```

The broadcast seems to happen only once at the end of all the responses received, even though I can see many *request!* in the console log.

How must I manage my global spinner/loader?

**EDIT**
I wish to show a loader/spinner in my navbar whenever data is being loaded.

Comment: what do you want to achieve using this

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal edit: purposes added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$watch` function doesn't listen for broadcast messages.  It watches for changes on the scope.  In this case, you are calling a function whenever `$rootScope.spin` changes, which gets called (by default) immediately, which is why you got called once.

The `$on` function is what you want here, as it is what will listen to broadcast events.

```
$rootScope.$on('spin', function(msg, data) {
    console.info('spin');
    $scope.spinner++;
});
```

I've put together a complete working example if you are curious:

http://codepen.io/BrianGenisio/pen/wIBHz

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using watcher you should just use on in the module run function

```
angular.module('test',[]).run(['$rootScope' function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("$spin", function () {
        // set the spinner here 
    });

}]);
```

Comment: Where can I find more info on `run` and `$on` and `$broadcast`?

Comment: http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/api/angular.Module http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope